# Omit function properties from a typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I want to Omit all functions from an interface

```
interface Human {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  walk: () => void;
  talk: (word: string) => Promise<void>
}

type HumanWithoutFunctions = RemoveFunctions<Human>

/* expected result:

HumanWithoutFunctions {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
type RemoveFunctions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Function ? never : K]: T[K]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIFcC2cTIN4BQyyIcmEAXMgM5hSgDmA3EcnA5SVgEbQvEB3OABsA1lQAUASmQBeAHzIAbgHtgAE37IwI8cgkCVUdVVr0QDGQuQAFKCszBqEADyqN8ggF8CBMAE8ABxQAJQhMFSUIADF0EAQwYBUQahcAFUVZfABtAGlkUGRRCH8VGGQ0tmoKvIBdZAgAD0gQdWrY%20MTk5AB%20EggoqGQqXNqqNLqfPyCUDGwQAHVgMAALFXQwDoSklLlkMIiora6UlzmceSA)